# Why are the eigenvalues of this Sturm Liouville problem all positive?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions, wave-equation, sturm-liouville

I have this problem in my book$$(\rho R')'+\lambda \rho R=0$$ with the solution that is finite for $\rho \to 0$ and $R(\rho=1)=0$. The book says "it can be shown that the eigenvalues are all positive, of the for $\lambda=\mu^2$.It doesn't show how. So here's my try

**MY APPROACH**

$\lambda = 0$: $(\rho R')'=0$ which gives $\rho R' = A$ which then gives $R'=\frac{A}{\rho}$ and therefore $R=A\ln{(\rho)}+B$ Now the natural logarithm goes to minus infinity when $\rho$ approaches $0$ and therefore we know $A=0$. Hence $R=B$. However, we also know that $R(\rho=1)=0$ and this tells us that $B=0$. Hence for $\lambda=0$ we only have trivial solutions.

$\lambda <0$: Suppose $\lambda=-\mu^2$, then we have $(\rho R')'-\mu^2\rho R=0$

> However I don't know how to continue. Any idea on how to show that the eigenvalues are all positive?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, you can think of this equation as coming from separation of variables from the equation $$\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \rho^2}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \rho}=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$$ with boundary conditions $$T(\rho, 0)=f(\rho) \qquad 1 \leq \rho \leq 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad T(1,t)=0 \qquad t>0$$ describing the temperature in an infinitely long cylinder of radius $1$ using cylindrical polar coordinates, where the initial temperature distribution depends on $\rho $ only

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that the solutions for $\lambda \neq 0$ are combinations of $J_0(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$ and $Y_0(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$, the Bessel functions of the first and second kind. Are you familiar with the asymptotics of these for imaginary argument (in which case they are sometimes called modified Bessel functions)? If not see Abramowitz and Stegun.

Comment: @Ian I am really not familiar with them. We introduce those two Bessel functions starting from the example above, but we don't go much further, and it is not explained how to find those functions and why the eigenvalues are all positive

Comment: If you know the asymptotics then the situation is straightforward: $Y_0(\alpha i\rho)$ blows up at $\rho=0$ for nonzero real $\alpha$ while $J_0(\alpha i \rho)$ does not. So the issue is merely checking that $J_0(\alpha i)$ is not zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiply by $R$ and integrate from $0$ to $1$:
$$ 0=\int_0^1 ((\rho R')'R + \lambda \rho R^2) \, d\rho. $$
Now integrate the first term by parts:
$$ \int_0^1 ((\rho R')'R \, d\rho = \left[ \rho R'R \right]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \rho R'^2 \, d\rho. $$
The first term vanishes if we assume that $R'$ is bounded as well, so
$$ 0 = -\int_0^1 \rho R'^2 \, d\rho + \lambda  \int_0^1 \rho R^2 \, d\rho. $$
Both integrals are strictly positive, so $\lambda$ must also be. This argument will work for any Sturm–Liouville problem, provided it is properly formulated.

Comment: can we safely assume that $R'$ is bounded as well?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why we need that condition. Can we not just say that $1 R'(1)R(1)=0$ by the boundary condition and that $0R'(0)R(0)$ vanishes too?

Comment: @Euler_Salter The problem is that if $R'$ blows up fast enough near $0$ then $\lim_{\rho \to 0^+} \rho R'(\rho) R(\rho)$ may not be zero.

Comment: @Ian oh right..

Comment: It is a reasonable question whether one can actually prove this from just the assumption that $R$ is bounded, though. The obvious counter is that if $R' \sim a/r$, $R \sim a\log{r}$ is not bounded. I think one can produce pointwise bounds given bounds on $R$ and $(\rho R')'$, but I'm not completely sure. Besides, if one can't cancel that term, the associated Sturm–Liouville operator is not self-adjoint anyway, so it's not a true Sturm–Liouville problem.

Comment: Come to think of it, this equation has a regular singular point at zero, so the Frobenius theory tells you $R \sim k \rho^{\sigma}$ or $k \rho^{\sigma}\log{\rho}$ as $\rho \to 0$, which is enough to show that $\rho RR'$ tends to zero if $R$ is bounded.

Comment: @Chappers what is $\sigma$ here?

Comment: A root of the indicial equation, which you find by putting a power of $\rho$ into the equation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method .

Answer (score 1):

One solution of Bessel's equation (without the right endpoint condition) is
$$
    R_{\lambda}(r)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda^k\frac{(-1)^k\rho^{2k}}{2^{2k}(k!)^2}.         
$$
A second linearly independent solution is obtained by variation of parameters, from which it can be shown that the second solution $S_{\lambda}$ is singular at $\rho=0$ because $R_{\lambda}(\rho)=1$ at $\rho=0$:
$$
        S_{\lambda}(\rho) = R_{\lambda}(\rho)\int\frac{1}{\rho R_{\lambda}(\rho)}d\rho.
$$
So any eigenvalue of your problem satisfying the right endpoint equation is a solution of the power series equation $R_{\lambda}(1)=0$. Of course $\lambda$ must be real, and it is obvious from the form of the power series in $\lambda$ that $\lambda \ge 0$ must hold because all terms of the power series $R_{\lambda}(1)$ are positive for $\lambda$ real and negative. What also comes out of this argument is the fact that the eigenvalues have no finite point of accumulation because they are the zeros of an entire function.

Comment: It makes sense a bit.. but al these proofs are somehow "backwards" aren't they? I mean normally when you solve  a SL problem you find the eigenvalues and then the eigenfunctions. But you are starting from the eigenfunctions and going back to the eigenvalues. Is there a proof that doesnt assume we know the solutions?

Comment: @Euler_Salter : All classical separation of variables problems start by finding the eigenfunctions. Then, in the process of satisfying the endpoint conditions, one uncovers the permissible eigenvalues. That's what I'm doing here as well. It's rare to be able to determine the full spectrum without knowing the classical eigenfunctions.

Comment: @Euler_Salter : To answer your question about being able to show positivity without knowing the eigenfunctions, the answer is "yes" and "no." Yes, you can determine positivity once you know the asymptotic behavior of all functions $f$ in the domain of the operator, which is to say $f \in L^2_{\rho}$, $Lf = -(\rho f')' \in L^2$. But this requires at least knowing the solutions of $Lf=0$, which are easily obtained in this case. The solutions of $Lf=0$ determine the asymptotic behaviors of all classical eigenfunction solutions of $Lf=\lambda f$.